# Windows 10 drive locked, MBR faulty

Tags: windows-10, mbr, bcd, windows-insider

two months ago I had my Windows 10 insider preview, but I couldn't update it for some reasons, so I got warnings saying that this insider build will expire soon.
I didn't touch my laptop for days, until when I turned it on again to copy some files, but I got an error that a windows boot file has an invalid digital signature, after so many wrestlings with boot files, I ended up with removing the bootmgr in a hope that the startup repair would recreate a valid one, which didn't.
Now this is my final status:

- Refreshing fails with an error "The Windows drive is locked...".
- System Reserved drive is the active boot partition.
- Windows startup error asserts that `winload.exe` has an invalid digital signature, but if I press enter it will start to boot and will fail loading the kernel `ntoskrnl.exe` as it's missing or corrupt.
- RebuildBcd fails with "The requested system device cannot be found.".
- ChkDsk healthy, SFC healthy.

If you need more details, comment what I didn't mention.

Comment: How are you finding some of this out?  If this Windows installation won't boot, it sounds like you're booting something else.  (Are you booting from a CD?)  What operating system are you booting?  I would think the Windows 10 installation process could fix this, and may be (realistically/easily) necessary if you're wanting to end up with a working installation of Windows 10 again.

Comment: Windows repairing environment of course, from a USB2 disk. And, reinstalling Windows will be a huge disadvantage at the moment, It's definitely my very last choice.

Comment: "Of course?"  There are certainly other options, so clarification of how you were getting results were in order.  Off-topic comment: your profile seems to promote the idea of gender equality, wishing for the days that professional females, whom you also call girls, have it as well as men.  If you're so promoting gender equality, why use the "child" word for females, and the "adult" word for males? Isn't that a female-empowerment-advocate "no no"?  - Cheers

Comment: Sorry for that xD I was a bit messed up with these repair things, also my situation is updated so I'm updating the post as well. Also about the off-topic thing, I rather not use "women" as it gives the idea of having men as the primary gender and, as I call, girls as the secondary.

Comment: Thanks.  Now, getting back on topic.  "The requested system device cannot be found." makes it sound like the partition is gone.  Are you sure you're using BIOS with MBR, instead of (U)EFI with GPT?  I wonder if a "fix" could be as easy as disabling SecureBoot.  (Maybe the Insider build wasn't made quite as carefully, and didn't get signed.  It's a stretch, but that may be an easy fix to re-enable you to boot your prior installation.)  Yeah, I'm speculating.  But without things like partition starting/ending locations, types/IDs, etc., there's little for us to troubleshoot with.

Comment: Diskpart says that the disk is not GPT, so, that's the thing. Now take a look at the updated post, I've advanced a bit further. But there is a UEFI editing option in the repair env. I'm gonna investigate it.

Comment: Likely, more info, seems the repair env is running on UEFI, but the disk is not GPT. Also my Windows installation disk which boots over legacy, cannot even find the installed Windows, which is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Microsoft uses time-bound system files on Insider builds, which have an expiry timestamp. The same applies to their setup files. I had a very difficult struggling to use a 14342 setup ISO as a recovery tool, but it couldn't boot, messy screen and stuff... . So I used the old WinRE usb stick I had, to run the setup file in the 14342 usb stick, installed it on an empty partition (that's why I always keep some unallocated space ), but it couldn't boot, with the same signature error as the old one. After lots of tries to disable integrity checks and signature enforcement (which all ended up with the messy screen thing), I went to my UEFI settings and shifted the date field backwards, before all these things happened. That's it! Windows is loading normally!
Hope I solved this riddle for not just myself ☺